# How autologin on a webpage when the fields (username, password) are hidden elements with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, hidden-field

I have a remote PC that connects to an Internet provider using a local web page. The Internet connection is not very stable and I need to have it auto reconnected by itself.

I started to write a Python/Selenium script and here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# options for operating in headless mode
opts = Options()
opts.set_headless()
assert opts.headless

# initialize browser
browser = Firefox(options=opts)

# browse a target web page
browser.get('http://hotspot.networx.bg/login.html')

username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("my_user_name")
password.send_keys("my_pass")

# use css class of the button
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input.btn.btn-primary.btn-submit')
button.submit()

# close *browser for memory cleanup
browser.close()
```

Once the compiler reaches username.send_keys(...) it given an error that the element is hidden and can't be reached by keyboard. I have another script that is functional and similar to the above (I used it to logout the i-net connection) so the only issue is how to handle the so called hidden fields.

So here is the relevant section from the login web page that I have to use to auto login.

```
<div class="card-body">
    
    <form name="login" class="form-login" action="http://hotspot.networx.bg/login" method="post" onsubmit="return doLogin()">
        
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true">
        
        <div class="input-container">
            <span class="icon">Избери доставчик</span>
            <select name="provider" id="provider" class="input-field ">
                <option value="networx.bg">networx.bg</option>
                <option value="telnet.bg">telnet.bg</option>
            </select>
        </div>
              
        <div class="input-container">
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-user icon"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Потребител" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="input-container">
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-unlock icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="Парола" name="password">
        </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" value="Вход">

    </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Two elements are hidden in the script. Could you try to **modify the type="hidden" to "visible"** ?

```
property_1 = "visible"
driver.execute_script("""
    let [property_1 ] = arguments
    document.querySelector('[name=dst]').type = property_1 
                """, property_1)
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathan. It seems that your code is valid, I added it to my script before my "send_keys" rows. I also replicated it for '[name=popup]' {the other hidden field} which ran also fine. Still on the usedname.send_keys I get the same error: "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input name="username type="hidden"> is not reachable by keyboard." Can I get that field just to accept a value instead of having to enter it by the keyboard?

Comment: I decided to add the above code also for 'username' and 'password' fields. Now I don't get any errors but I don't connected to Internet either :)

Comment: Update on what I have tried: Some text based browsers (e.g. lynx) but since they don't support JavaScript they were of no use. I tested also 'browsh' which claims to support JavaScript but it seems even less functional than lynx.
In the end I need a dirty hack: in this case it is called SikuliX. I am going to record all my mouse and keyboard clicks and when my i-net connection is down the script will turn it back on just I would do manually. Voila!